# Angular 4 with Java as Backend on a single server

Tags: java, angular

I want to use angular 4 with java as backend. What I need is a single war file.I dont want to run different server for front end and back end. I want that there will be single java war file so that I can deploy it on app server like tomcat or jboss.
Please suggest some approach. Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: believe it or not, but just because it isn't in the same war file doesn't mean you can't run it on the same tomcat/jboss instance.

Comment: I am new in angular 4.. can you please suggest some approach to use angular 4 with java backend with spring and without spring as well. I searched on net aswell but mostly I found with spring boot and both are running on diiferent server.

Comment: for using angular, what you use for backend is irrelevant. You can easily create a rest service that can be consumed by an angular front-end. That takes ... twenty minutes, tops? There are enough online sources you can look this up on.

Comment: I based my build from [this github example](https://github.com/ashishdoneriya/TransactionManager).

Comment: @NicoVanBelle thank you.. Is there any source without maven.so that I can refer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HI I have done this in my project and what can you do that when you take a build of your Angular2 application then after the build copy all the content from the build/install folder and paste it in your Java Work space as a static content inside WebContent  folder.
Makesure that you correctly configured the url of the backend service in your angular code.
After that try to clean the tomcat server and then restart it.
I hope it will work.

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion. It seems to be helpful. I have one question can you please explain me the meaning of 'Makesure that you correctly configured the url of the backend service in your angular code'. Right now i am giving path of backend service(REST API) as 'localhost:8080/xyz..'. is it right way?

Comment: @NishantVarshney that would depend on the code of your rest service.

Comment: Suppose your services are deployed at http://192.168.3.4/<Context Root>/<End_url> so while hitting the url you have to configure the same depending on your method call.

Comment: Please accept the answer if helpful.

Comment: @Stultuske...  I dont want to give 'localhost' in my code for accessing the rest service. But as it is on different server as well different dynamic java web project I am doing this. Can you please suggest me any other way to consume that java REST API without using localhost? Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: you can use the ip address or use the domain url provided by your domain provider ,if it is in your local provide http://127.0.0.1/....

Comment: @so_what.. I understand your point.. But actually I don't want to use any server URL as hard coded< '192.168.3.4' in your case>. As i am getting at my level I can get that server URL using some property file configuration or if angular provides some new way to do this please let me know.

Comment: you can create the constant file in your angular2 and provide the url there.
Then import the constant file in your angular services and use that.

Comment: @so_what... Thank you for your suggestion. I get the way.. I will try in same manner you suggested and if needed come back to you.. again thank you for your help..

Comment: no problem ,can your please accept the answer if you are ok with this.

Comment: by deploying it on a server which is configured to answer to another address. If you don't want to hardcode the address, use a .properties file